# Unable to install cordova through npm

Tags: cordova, npm

I was trying to install cordova through npm but every time i got `ETIMEDOUT` issue can anyone suggest me how to do that?

`npm install -g cordova error`

Comment: I have had same thing and I reinstall node.js then install it again and it works

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's a proxy issue. Try running the following commands before running npm install

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy_host:port
npm config set https-proxy https://proxy_host:port
```

You should be able to get your proxy settings from a free proxy detector, for example http://www.blockstatus.com/ip-proxy-detector

Comment: yes thanks but can you tell me how to get my proxy_host of my system.